# How to properly run spock test using testcontainers in spring boot

Tags: spock, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I have a spring boot app, with test written using `spock` and `testcontainers` (mysql). What I've made is working fine, but it doesn't feel right (f.e. becuase `@sql` goes for each test iteration so I have to use `INSERT IGNORE ...` in my sql script. I am also not happy about the trick with static and non-static mysqlcontainer). 
I am a total beginner when it comes to testcontainers (and spock actually) so If some could tell me how to make it better using `spock`, `@sql`, datasource and `testcontainers` I would be grateful.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = Initializer.class)
@Testcontainers
class GeneratorTest extends Specification {

    public static MySQLContainer staticMySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer()
            .withDatabaseName("test")
            .withUsername("test")
            .withPassword("test")

    @Shared
    public MySQLContainer mySQLContainer = mySQLContainer;

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        void initialize(@NotNull ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues values = TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + staticMySQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + staticMySQLContainer.getPassword(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + staticMySQLContainer.getUsername()
            )
            values.applyTo(configurableApplicationContext)
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService
    @Autowired
    private BikeRepository bikeRepository

    @Sql("/testdata/insert_into_cars.sql")
    def "validate number of doors"(int carId, int expectedNrOfDoors) {
        given:
        Car car = carService.getById(carId)

        expect:
        car.getNrOfDoors() == expectedNrOfDoors

        where:
        carId || expectedNrOfDoors
        1     || 3
        2     || 3
        3     || 5
    }
}
```

---

**Updated (use of jdbc-based containers)**:
When it comes to [`JDBC-based containers`](https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/database_containers.html#jdbc-url) I'm not sure If I set it up correctly. I've created `application-test.properties` in `test/resources` directory. I've put there:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0.12://localhost:3306/shop?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

and my test class looks like:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
class GeneratorTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService

    <skipped for brevity>
```

When I try to run the test class I'm keep getting:

```
    2018-11-20 19:10:25.409 2612@DESKTOP-MLK30PF  INFO --- [main]  [mysql:8.0.12].waitUntilContainerStarted : Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:32770/shop using query 'SELECT 1' (JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:128) 
2018-11-20 19:12:25.420 2612@DESKTOP-MLK30PF ERROR --- [main]  [mysql:8.0.12].tryStart : Could not start container (GenericContainer.java:297) 
org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:53)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:129)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:292)
```

followed by

```
2018-11-20 19:12:25.486 2612@DESKTOP-MLK30PF  INFO --- [tc-okhttp-stream-242833949]  [mysql:8.0.12].accept : STDERR: 2018-11-20T18:10:44.918132Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.12'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL. (Slf4jLogConsumer.java:32) 
2018-11-20 19:12:25.487 2612@DESKTOP-MLK30PF  INFO --- [main]  [mysql:8.0.12].tryStart : Creating container for image: mysql:8.0.12 (GenericContainer.java:253) 
2018-11-20 19:12:25.609 2612@DESKTOP-MLK30PF  INFO --- [main]  [mysql:8.0.12].tryStart : Starting container with ID: de75c9dafed8032b84cb827bf43a29c1964bfe4e168422272c9310a4803fd856 (GenericContainer.java:266) 
2018-11-20 19:12:25.896 2612@DESKTOP-MLK30PF  INFO --- [main]  [mysql:8.0.12].tryStart : Container mysql:8.0.12 is starting: de75c9dafed8032b84cb827bf43a29c1964bfe4e168422272c9310a4803fd856 (GenericContainer.java:273) 
2018-11-20 19:12:25.901 2612@DESKTOP-MLK30PF  INFO --- [main]  [mysql:8.0.12].waitUntilContainerStarted : Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:32772/shop using query 'SELECT 1' (JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:128)
```

---

for issues with mysql version `8` look [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/736)

**UPDATE (solved):** 
As @bsideup pointed out jdbc-based containers is the best solution for this use case. It works perfectly fine as I decsribed above, but I had to change mysql version from `8` to lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [JDBC-based containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/database_containers.html#jdbc-url)?

Comment: good point, still some troubles, probably from wrong configuration, I've updated my post If you wanted to take a look, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work with version `8`.  It's suggested to use `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`. Is it possible to pass in jdbc-based containers ? https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/736

Comment: it works now, starting with Testcontainers 1.11.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
def setupSpec(){ //or use setup(){ if not a @Shared Container
System.getProperties()
                    .putAll([
                            "spring.datasource.url"     : mySQLContainer...,
                            "spring.datasource.username": mySQLContainer...,
                            "spring.datasource.password": mySQLContainer...
                    ])
}
```

then you can get rid of the staticMySQLContainer

and also the Initializer